# reading smalltalk code from gst prompt

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

This is simple GNU Smalltalk question. Sorry, but just could not find how to do this.

I'm playing with gnu smalltalk, I know I can do

```
% gst <file-name>
```

but if I already in gst> prompt, how can I read a file into memory (file that contains code), something like TCL source command.

thanks and applogies again for the simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
st> fd := FileDescriptor open: './myfile.st'
<FileDescriptor on "/Users/math/myfile.st">
st> fd fileIn
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [package](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk//manual/html_node/Packages.html)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use class FileStream, whose superclass is FileDescriptor belonged to Streams-Files.

May the link below help you

http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/gst-base.html#FileStream

here is a sample code:

```
at: #f put: (FileStream  open: '/root/test'  mode: FileStream read) !
f do: [ :c | Transcript nextPut: c ] !
25 timesRepeat: [ Transcript nextPut: (f next) ] ! 
f close !
```